# What dishes pair well with black wine?

Tags: wine, recommendations, pairing, red-wine

What food stuffs pair well with black wine?

Black wine in reality is a very, very dark red wine and I would like to know what pairs well with this wine as well as if there are specials occasions that pair well with this wine if any.

> Wait, what the heck is black wine? Despite its nickname, it’s a red wine made from Saperavi grapes—but its color is such a rich, dark purple, that it looks black. Saperavi is Georgia’s most popular red wine, and the grapes are now being grown throughout the world, including the Finger Lakes region of the U.S., Australia and Eastern Europe. - [Psst: Black Wine Is the New Trend You Need to Know](https://www.purewow.com/wine/georgian-black-wine-saperavi-grapes)

Comment: If this is anything like the Kindzmarauli (also Georgian and deep [sweetish] red) I find it goes well with meats, no so much with poultry and fish. Haven’t tried it together with dairy products. (Sorry, can’t name particular meat dishes.)

Comment: @Oliver If you can, please go ahead and based an answer on your comment.

Comment: Incidentally, was at a wine store today and opted to try a Saperavi, thanks to your question, but was told by a salesman that they’re much drier than the Kindzmarauli. In that case, I can’t suggest dishes that pair with the latter. (Nevertheless, could be the guy was just spewing and never even tried it; he just reiterated its label back to me. Awaits more research for a good answer.)

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work. I've changed it to what I think it was intended to be.

Comment: May I suggest Wild Boar?

Comment: @dougal5.0.0 You sure can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve never tried it myself, but I did find [an article](https://vinepair.com/articles/what-is-black-wine/)  which includes some pairings. From that article:

> It’s an excellent food wine as well; black wines pair well with fatty
>   meats, fried vegetables, walnuts (widely used in Georgian cuisine),
>   and cheeses.

By the way, the page you linked in your question has its own pairing suggestions:

> **Got it. So what should I drink it with?** Gersamia suggests pairing
>   Lukasi Saperavi 2014 ($44), just recently available in the U.S., with
>   pork, lamb, grilled chicken, grilled tuna or aged cheese.

Answer (score 5):

[Saperavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saperavi) is a [Teinturier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teinturier) type grape, which usually means red skins and red flesh. I have grown two of these types of grapes. Dunkelfelder and Agria and they both are used to make deep red wines that are almost undrinkable. They are usually used in very small quantities to boost the color of lighter colored grapes like Pinot Noir. On their own you need to take special care in the winery to have a light hand in the wine making area otherwise you end up with a tannic monster that you can't drink. You can pretty easily buy a similar grape in the USA called [Alicante Bouchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicante_Bouschet) which has been grown in California for over 100 years. You can usually buy them at a decent wine shop. I have had Saperavi wines and they tend to be huge tannic monsters unless tamed in the winery.

Pair with food as you would Cabernet or Nebbiolo, red meats, bold cheeses, heavy sauces, etc.

Comment: Personally, I prefer your answer since it is based on actual experience. Interestingly, I've also seen the term "black wine" applied to Malbecs from Cahors in France. Also a pretty opaque wine.

Comment: Any of those super dark wines I would say that food pairings would be similar. French Malbec could be as dark and tannic as Saperavi. For whatever reason, new world Malbecs aren't as tannic. I know my Malbecs were not